# WSO2: APIM scope apim:subscribe can be added to WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have integrated WSO2 (IS-KM-5.6.0) with APIM 2.5.0.

I am using below command to generate access token with default scope

curl -u : -k -d "grant_type=password&username=ldapuser@local.com@carbon.super&password=password" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:9445/oauth2/token

it gives me proper access token with scope as default. Below is the result of the above command:

{"access_token":"5218d614-e327-379f-819a-b9572daa106d","refresh_token":"4ed7484d-ca30-31c1-8bce-e778f4aab6fd","scope":"default","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":2568}

But, I am unable to use this in invoking the rest APIs of APIM (publisher rest APIs) to perform below activities:
a) getting store application details
b) adding applications etc etc

I read in WSO2 documents that to use the store and publisher restAPIs, only scopes which are available for APIM store and publisher can only be used.

So,Can these store or publisher restAPIs be invoked without scopes (apim:subscribe) or is there any other way to do so?

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The store or publisher restAPIs can't be invoked without scopes. 
For publisher & store there are separate scope. Scope for store & for creating application is same `apim:subscribe`. Scope for publisher related apis is `apim:api_view`. You can get api specific scopes from [store](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/apidocs/store/) & [publisher](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/apidocs/publisher/) api documentation. FYI you can specify multiple scopes in one shot as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How Can I specify multiple scopes in one request? Can you please throw some light on that

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot AshwinK

Comment: This is how you specify multiple scopes in one request `apim:api_view apim:api_publish apim:subscribe` (separate it by space)